# php fopen silently failing

Tags: php, fopen

I'm haveing trouble opening this url useing fopen

> http://sim8430.agni.lindenlab.com:12046/cap/ccab53e3-49d8-c4f8-b3ad-51ff22c1fa17/

however it silently fails for some reason, it opens other urls just fine but no urls like the one above

the fact that it doesnt give an error is not the real problem, the not loading is what im trying to fix

```
$file = fopen("http://sim8430.agni.lindenlab.com:12046/cap/ccab53e3-49d8-c4f8-b3ad-51ff22c1fa17/", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
```

Comment: Crystal ball broken. Try later.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the owner of that URL is blocking PHP as a user agent to prevent you downloading the content programmatically.

Comment: im able to open it from my local webserver, but it isnt running from my paid webhost, even if the php setting are exactly the same

Comment: use cURl, code below, in answer section

Answer (score 1):

catch it like this instead

```
// add extensive logging
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$file = fopen("http://sim8430.agni.lindenlab.com:12046/cap/xyz/", "r");
if($file === false) { 
      // try through socket open
      $file = fsockopen("sim8430.agni.lindenlab.com", 12046, $errno, $errstr);
      if($file == false && $errno == 0) die("Socket initialization failed");
      else if(!$file) {
          die($errstr);
      } else {
          $out = "GET /cap/xyz/ HTTP/1.1\r\n";
          $out .= "Host: sim8430.agni.lindenlab.com\r\n";
          $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
          fwrite($file, $out);
      }
}
if($file) {
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $contents = fgets($file, 128);
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: That still isn't going to explain why it failed.

Comment: it will.. fopen 100% triggers error output if something is not right. depending your verbosity level and severity of error - you will get the printout

Comment: very well, try the above then, its more or less as low level it can get - and if the `$errstr` does not contain any errors - consult you webhotel admin and tell them that you ned communications on ports other the 80.

Answer (score 0):

Always use cURL when reading/parsing a file content that is on the WWW server.

```
<?php

class CurlTool {

    public static $userAgents = array(
        'FireFox3' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0',
        'GoogleBot' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
        'IE7' => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)',
        'Netscape' => 'Mozilla/4.8 [en] (Windows NT 6.0; U)',
        'Opera' => 'Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 6.0; U; en)'
    );
    public static $options = array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)',
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "cookies.txt",
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "cookies.txt",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            //CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => false,
    );
    private static $proxyServers = array();
    private static $proxyCount = 0;
    private static $currentProxyIndex = 0;
    public static $getinfo;

    public static function addProxyServer($url) {
        self::$proxyServers[] = $url;
        ++self::$proxyCount;
    }

    public static function fetchContent($url, $fields = null, $verbose = false) {
        //print '*'.$fields.'*';
        if (($curl = curl_init($url)) == false) {
            throw new Exception("curl_init error for url $url.");
        }
        if (self::$proxyCount > 0) {
            $proxy = self::$proxyServers[self::$currentProxyIndex++ % self::$proxyCount];
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
            if ($verbose === true) {
                echo "Reading $url [Proxy: $proxy] ... ";
            }
        } else if ($verbose === true) {
            echo "Reading $url ... ";
        }
        //$verbose=TRUE;
        //print_r($fields);
//        debug_print_backtrace();
//url-ify the data for the POST
        $fields_string = '';
        if (is_array($fields))
            foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
                if (empty($key))
                    continue;
                $fields_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
                if ($verbose === true) {
                    echo $key . ": " . $value;
                }
            }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        if (count($fields) > 0) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        }

        if ($verbose === true) {
            echo "Fields string $fields_string ... ";
        }

        curl_setopt_array($curl, self::$options);

        $content = curl_exec($curl);
        self::$getinfo = curl_getinfo($curl);
        if ($content === false) {
            throw new Exception("curl_exec error for url $url " . curl_error($curl));
        }

        curl_close($curl);
        if ($verbose === true) {
            echo "Done.\n";
        }
        $content = preg_replace('#\n+#', ' ', $content);
        $content = preg_replace('#\s+#', ' ', $content);

        return $content;
    }

    public static function downloadFile($url, $fileName, $fields = null, $verbose = false) {
        if (($curl = curl_init($url)) == false) {
            throw new Exception("curl_init error for url $url.");
        }


        if (self::$proxyCount > 0) {
            $proxy = self::$proxyServers[self::$currentProxyIndex++ % self::$proxyCount];
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
            if ($verbose === true) {
                echo "Downloading $url [Proxy: $proxy] ... ";
            }
        } else if ($verbose === true) {
            echo "Downloading $url ... ";
        }

        //url-ify the data for the POST
        $fields_string = '';
        if (is_array($fields))
            foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
                if (empty($key))
                    continue;
                $fields_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
            }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

        curl_setopt_array($curl, self::$options);

        if (is_file($fileName)) {
            $contents = file_get_contents($fileName, false, null, -1, 3 * 1024);
            $pattern = "__VIEWSTATE";
            if (strpos($contents, $pattern) === false) {
                return $fileName;
            }
        }

//        if (is_file($fileName)) {
//            // make a HEAD request and try to get the file size HEAD
//            // if they differ then redownload the file, otherwise no need
//            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
//            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
//            $ret = curl_exec($curl);
//            //echo $fileName;
//            $size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
//            if ($size == filesize($fileName)) {
//                return $fileName;
//            } else {
//                unlink($fileName);
//                return self::downloadFile($url, $fileName, $fields, $verbose);
//            }
//        }

        if (substr($fileName, -1) == '/') {
            $targetDir = $fileName;
            $fileName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'c_');
        }
        if (($fp = fopen($fileName, "w")) === false) {
            throw new Exception("fopen error for filename $fileName");
        }



        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

        $ret = curl_exec($curl);
        self::$getinfo = curl_getinfo($curl);

        if ($ret === false) {
            fclose($fp);
            unlink($fileName);
            throw new Exception("curl_exec error for url $url.");
        } elseif (isset($targetDir)) {
            $eurl = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
            preg_match('#^.*/(.+)$#', $eurl, $match);
            fclose($fp);
            rename($fileName, "$targetDir{$match[1]}");
            $fileName = "$targetDir{$match[1]}";
        } else {
            fclose($fp);
        }

        curl_close($curl);
        if ($verbose === true) {
            echo "Done.\n";
        }
        return $fileName;
    }

}

?>
```

cURL always send browser headers, and you will not get time out, or be redirected or die effect

download the file or fetch file content, your choice !